# Excel VBA import data from ASCII file and make average for plot

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting data from some sensors in a huge ASCII file that I want to import to excel to make the average and plot, I'm importing successfully, but I don't know how to make the average of the columns automatically

```
    Sub Import()
Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim OpenBook As Workbook
Dim NameOfWorkbook As String
Dim arr As Variant
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet).Name = "Data1"
NameOfWorkbook = ActiveSheet.Name

'Step 1 Import the data

FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Import sensor report in ASCII format")
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    arr = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    RowCount = UBound(arr, 1)
    ColumnCount = UBound(arr, 2)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data1").Range("A1").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value = arr
    arr = OpenBook.Sheets(1).Range("A3").CurrentRegion
    RowCount = UBound(arr, 1)
    ColumnCount = UBound(arr, 2)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data1").Range("A3").Resize(RowCount, ColumnCount).Value = arr
    OpenBook.Close False
    End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This import the sensor number in row 1 and the data from row 3 and below
I would like to automatically fill row 2 with the average of row3 and below to the last number, which may vary, please find a pic below

[image]

So, can anyone help me to automatically fill cell D2 with " =Average(D3:D last item)" for D2 to AJ2? using the same execution as the import code?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your problem not knowing what formula to use?  Or is it that you don't know how to insert a formula?  If the former, `AVERAGE` will ignore empty cells, so you can just enter a formula that covers down to the bottom.  If the latter, look at the `.Formula` property of the `.Range` object for guidance.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply, my problem is I don't know how to exactly wrote the formula so in a loop, it goes from column D to column AJ and inserts the average value of that column, ignoring the first 2 cells.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this function.

```
Private Function RangeAverage(ByVal Rs As Long) As Double
    ' Rs is the row number to take the average from
    
    Dim Rng     As Range            ' working range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data1")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(Rs, "D"), .Cells(Rs, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
    End With
    RangeAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Rng)
End Function
```

You can integrate it into your project with code like this:-

```
Dim R As Long

For R = 3 To LastRow
     MyCell.Value = RangeAverage(R)
Next R
```

where `Mycell` is a cell in any worksheet that changes with `R`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I've tried doing this but can't make it work, I'm going through your code and I think it puts in column D the average of that Row, but I hope this give me a start, Thanks!

Comment: I am trying something like: `For R = 4 To LastRow
     Data1.cell(2, R).Value = Application.Average.Range(.Cells(2, R), .Cells(60002, R))` but can't make it work aparently :/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your help, which has allowed me to find the solution below, I'm sure expert ppl around could do it in a more efficient way and I'm open to suggestions:

```
Dim R As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long
For R = 4 To 36
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, R).End(xlDown).Row
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data1")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(3, R), .Cells(lRow, R))
    End With
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data1").Cells(2, R).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(Rng)
Next R
```

Comment: One of the problems I had is as I was selecting the range using .Range(Cells(),Cells()) the coma that separated the cells in the range was being read by excel as different arguments of the Average function, resulting in the average of the first and last item, not the whole list, so using a variable (Rng) to select the range independently avoid the use of comas inside the Average function and solve the problem. Thanks!